# Check for common element in two arrays using FFT

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, fourier-transform

My task asks me to check whether there is a common element in two sets $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$, $\{y_1,y_2,...,y_n\}$ with $x_i,y_i\in\mathbb{N}$ using the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT).
(I'm aware that there is a simple $O(n\log(n))$ algorithm to solve this problem using sorting and binary search.)
The tasks hints that we should consider the following product to solve the problem:
$$
\prod_{1\leq i,j \leq n} (x_i-y_j)
$$
The product is obviously zero if there is a common element, but I am still not sure how I could compute it faster via FFT.
I know how to use FFT to multiply polynomials efficiently, but somehow I seem to overlook something.

Comment: I think the product that is zero if and only if there is a common element would be $\prod_{1\leq i,j\leq n}(x_i-y_j)$. This is equal to to the product $\prod_{i=1}^{n}p(x_i)$, where $p(x)=\prod_{j=1}^{n}(x-y_j)$.

Comment: sorry, you are right

Comment: @NotDijkstra: in fact, you can compute $p(x)$ as a polynomial using divide-and-conquer + FFT multiplication. After that, you need to evaluate $p$ in $n$ points. It is also a classical problem (so called *multi-point evaluation*) that can be solved in $O(n \log^2 n)$ time using FFT multiplication. Of course, this method is very arcane and slow compared to simple $O(n \log n)$ binary-search based solution, but I think this is exactly what plshelp is looking for.

Comment: thanks i think that's the algorithm i was searching for

Answer (score 1):

This one is a bit esoteric, but:

$$
\prod_{1\leq i,j \leq n} (x_i-y_j)
$$

Could be decomposed to (as noted by @NotDijkstra)

$$
\prod_{i=1}^{n} p(x_i)
$$
where
$$
p (x) = \prod_{j=1}^{n} (x - y_j)
$$

reduces to a polynomial with roots $y_i$. Coefficients of this polynomial could be computed with FFT, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.01357.pdf. It could be done even faster using divide and conquer strategy - recursively split the formula into two polynomials and multiply them with FFT ([see answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465398/given-all-roots-how-do-i-find-the-coefficients-of-a-polynomial-in-time-faster-t)).

Polynomial representation in its turn would allow [fast exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) of x, or even [multi-point evaluation](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/CAG/theses/justine.pdf)

Although, I don't see any advantages over traditional approach in terms of speed or complexity except if it's implemented on specialised ASICs/FPGAs/GPUs.

Comment: Interesting paper, however the runtime is $nN+O(n\log(n))$ and the author writes that N*n is $O(n^2)$. The idea to split the problem up is still a good start i think.

Comment: It seems like $p(x)$ polynomial could be evaluated on X in n log n using FFT - http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/CAG/theses/justine.pdf. But I couldn’t find a fast way to compute coefficients. So it’s still $n^2$.

Comment: @plshelp actually: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465398/given-all-roots-how-do-i-find-the-coefficients-of-a-polynomial-in-time-faster-t

Answer (score 0):

*It seems you want to use Vandermand's matrix.*

> Let's say the arrays have unique values in each of them(remember we need distinct values of \begin{equation}
> (x_k) 's
> \end{equation} for k=1,...len(array1)+len(array2) to work for the property of "**Uniqueness of interpolating polynomial**") and we know the fact that at least one of them is common in the two arrays.
>
> > Now combine the arrays and calculate ***Determinant of Vandermand's Matrix*** which had to be nonsingular if all the x's and y's combined were distinct.
> > Since we know there is a common element, the determinant of Vandermand's matrix must be 0, i.e,
> > \begin{equation}
> > \\\prod_{0<=j<k<=2n-1}(x_k-x_j)=0\\
> > \end{equation}

> > I wouldn't call it an efficient algorithm because solving the eqn using LU decomposition algorithms provides us with time complexity of O($n^3$) while even a faster algorithm like Lagrange's Formula would only get us to O($n^2$).